# All Intel 1155 socket motherboards only support up to 32GB, why?

Tags: motherboard

I want to buy an Intel CPU (with quad-core) and a motherboard that supports more than 32GB. I was looking for a motherboard that has a 1155 socket and 64GB maximum memory support. However, from what I found, the max memory I can find is 32GB.

Is this a technical limitation for 32GB of RAM, or have I just not been looking in the right places for a motherboard?

Comment: I reworded the question so it should no longer be a shopping request, hopefully it will be good enough to re-open the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked at various motherboards - all seem to say a maximum of 32GB of memory, the chipsets (which state the same) and the processors...

All of the 1155 pin processors I can find only seem to support a maximum of 32GB of memory at the CPU level, so, I don't think this is possible.

Even entry level servers (Xeon 3xxx) that are based on the 1155 CPU package state a maximum of 32GB of memory.

It isn't until you get to the Xeon 5xxx series that you see bigger memory allowances, so, I believe this limitation is on the actual 1155 package processor itself.

Comment: For the curious, this is because Intel now integrates the memory management unit for their CPUs directly into the CPU die now - and thus, the maximum memory limits come from a combination of available motherboard hardware, and the actual CPU model itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately LGA1155 only supports 32GB